# Jcrop crop_x set correctly in the view, but never present in Model in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jcrop

**Context**

I have implemented an ImageUploader (with CarrierWave, MiniMagic and ImageMagic) in my Rails app being developed on Cloud9, and it seems to work well with image resizing both in Development and in Production.

**Situation**

Following this implementation, comes my problem: I have been trying to implement Image Cropping using JCrop following Ryan Bates' [RailsCasts #182 Cropping Images (revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images-revised?autoplay=true), but there are two issues that can't seem to figure out.

**Issues**

I can select the area to crop and the Preview shows exactly what I need, but:

1. The cropped area does not show the resizing squares on the corners, nor does it show the JCrop.gif;
2. The attributes crop_x, crop_y, crop_w and crop_h are never present in the model, so when I run `crop_x.present?` I always get `nil`.

**Relevant Code**

Gemfile

```
gem "carrierwave", '1.1.0'
gem "mini_magick", '4.7.0'
```

crop.html.erb

```
<div class="col-sm-8" style="padding: 40px; text-align: left;">
<h4>Image to Crop</h4>
    <%= image_tag @user.picture.url, id: "target" %>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4" style="padding: 40px; text-align: left;">
    <h4>Preview</h4>
    <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; overflow: hidden;">
        <%= image_tag @user.picture.url, id: "preview" %>
    </div>
    <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
        <% %w[x y w h].each do |attribute| %>
            <%= f.text_field "crop_#{attribute}" %><br>
        <% end %>
        <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit "Crop", class: "btn btn-success btn-lg" %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

user.rb

```
mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
attr_accessor :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h, :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token  
after_update :crop_picture

...

def crop_picture
    if crop_x.present?
        picture.recreate_versions!
    end
end
```

users.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
    new PictureCropper()

class PictureCropper
    constructor: ->
        $('#target').Jcrop
            aspectRatio: 0
            onSelect: @update
            onChange: @update

    update: (coords) =>
        $('#user_crop_x').val(coords.x)
        $('#user_crop_y').val(coords.y)
        $('#user_crop_w').val(coords.w)
        $('#user_crop_h').val(coords.h)
        @updatePreview(coords)
    
    updatePreview: (coords) =>
        $('#preview').css
            width: Math.round(100/coords.w * $('#target').width()) + 'px'
            height: Math.round(100/coords.h * $('#target').height()) + 'px'
            marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(100/coords.w * coords.x) + 'px'
            marginTop: '-' + Math.round(100/coords.h * coords.y) + 'px'
```

**Solutions I've tried**

- I uninstalled the CarrierWave and MiniMagic gems, reinstalled ImageMagick;
- I changed the JCrop css file to access the Jcrop.gif accordingly;
- I updated JQuery;

It all boils down to crop_x,y,h,w is not being passed to the model from my view form.

**Disclaimer**

I know this seems to be a very punctual problem, but I've been struggling with this for almost a week now, and I've read maybe 30 to 40 blog posts and forum discussions, and I haven't found anyone with the same issue.

Any help or comments appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: When you do "crop_#{attribute}" you create those attributes in the form. Just make sure you apply them to your model in your controller: user.crop_x = params[:crop_x] etc..

Comment: May actually be: @myuser.crop_x = params[:user][:crop_x]. Myuser being the user you just created in the controller action

Comment: @Maxence, to do `user.crop_x = params...`, would I have to create a migration to make crop_x an attribute of my User model? Or somehow crop_x would be a temporary nested variable within my model, and would therefore be deleted upon saving the user? I believe the former is more likely than the latter, but I am curious.

Thank you a lot for the comments. They have already gotten me going in some direction. At this point I have created attributes for crop_x, crop_y, etc, and done exactly as you said. It seems to work very well.

Comment: The latter is true. Your attr accessors in your model are doing just that : create temporary methods, whereas no field exist in the database. You can create the fields in the dataabse too. Then you don't need the attr_accessors in your model I guess

Comment: Great, thank you. This closes issue #2 that I raised in this post. Would you have any insights for issue #1?

Comment: unfortunately not, as I have been using `cropper.js` I have little knowledge of `Jcrop`